# how to pass data along with files from angular controller to node server?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am passing some data from `angular.js` controller in following format:

```
data: { model: { title: 'hello'}, files: $scope.files}
```

I am able to get this in `node.js` by doing this:

`req.files`

Now I want to send one more data with existing data, so I tried doing this:

```
data: { model: { title: 'hello', id:newId}, files: $scope.files}
```

but when I did `req.id`. I am getting `undefined`.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: try this console.log(req.query)

Comment: okay, but I think `req.query` will contain queryString params. am i right?

Comment: is this post call or get call ?

Comment: if it is post call then console.log(req.body.data)

Comment: it's a `POST` request.

Comment: `console.log(req.body.data)`, showing undefined

Comment: try to find out ur data in console.log(req.body) because in post req the data is present in body of ajax call

Comment: on `console.log(req.body)`, getting `{ model: { title: 'hello', id : 100})`, but i cannot retrieve `id`  field out of that.

Comment: then try console.log(req.body.model.id)

Comment: `console.log(req.body.model.id) ` getting `undefined`

Comment: try console.log(req.body.model) it should give {title:;hello',id:100}

Comment: ok even `console.log(req.body.model.id)` gives `{title:;hello',id:100}`, how can I retrieve `id`  parameter out of it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158838/discussion-between-asad-and-mayank-bisht).

Answer (score 0):

In angular, pass by combining in formdata :

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("object", JSON.stringify($scope.yourJsonObject)); //pass json here
fd.append("files", $scope.files);

//wild card(*/*) consumes type
$http.post("Your URL", fd, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
});
```

Then retrive `object` and `files` separately by their names.

Comment: Okay, but the way I am sending data should also work.

Answer (score 0):

In post call the data is present in body of request obj try to find out your data in req obj like this

```
   console.log(req.body)
```

on server side

Comment: On console.log(req.body), getting { model: { title: 'hello', id : 100}), but i cannot retrieve id field out of that.

Comment: y u have  { model: { title: 'hello', id : 100}) round bracket at the end it should b curly

Comment: my bad, that's a typo, it's a `brace`.

Comment: u can get id from {title:;hello',id:100} like this
assign this to var a =req.body.model;
and then console.log(a.id) 
or console.log['id']

Comment: okay,
I tried with `req.body.model.id`, but I got `undefined`
I believe your code will also do the same thing, right?